# Constrain optimisation with duplicates

Tags: python, or-tools

I have a set of many (10000+) items, from which have I have to choose exactly `k` items. I can only choose each item multiple times subject to an ordering constraint: If I choose an item in position 1, I can't choose it until position 21. My items have profits, and costs.

Each item is represented as a tuple:

```
item = ('item name', cost, profit)
```

as an example

```
vase = ['Ming Vase', 1000, 10000]

plate = ['China Plate', 10, 5]
```

and the total set of items is a list of lists:

```
items = [item1, item2, ..., itemN].
```

My profits and costs are also lists:

```
profits = [x[2] for x in items]
costs = [x[1] for x in items]
```

For each item chosen, it needs to have a minimum value, and that item can't be reused within the next 19 items. I want to choose the k cheapest items with the highest value subject to this constraint, but I'm having difficulty formulating it.

I'm having trouble formulating this using google OR tools. The following just gets the best `k` (in this case 100) without any extra constraints

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

solver = pywraplp.Solver('SolveAssignmentProblemMIP',
                       pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

x = {}

for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
    x[i] = solver.BoolVar('x[%s]' % (i))

#Define the constraints 
total_chosen = 100
solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i] for i in range(MAX_ITEMS)]) == total_chosen)

max_cost = 5.0

for i in range(num_recipes):
    solver.Add(x[i] * cost[i] <= max_cost)

solver.Maximize(solver.Sum([profits[i] * x[i] for i in range(total_chosen)]))
sol = solver.Solve()
```

I can get the set of items I've chosen by:

```
for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
    if x[i].solution_value() > 0:
        print(item[i].item_name)
```

Any help in formulating the constraints and objective would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: First, you need to strictly formulate 'k cheapest items with the highest value'. 
Because there is a dozen mathematical formulation for that. 
You may try to optimize sum, max/min, order, to put constraints on the sum or max/min on each of criterion, calculate relative value dividing criteria etc. 

It seems you may exclude the repetition constraint from the formation. At a glance, if you may repeat an item, you must. So you need to assign only first 19 (20?) items, later (optimal) sequences should replicate first 19.

Comment: for i in range(num_recipes):
    solver.Add(x[i] * cost[i] <=max_cost) solver.Maximize(solver.Sum([profits[i] * x[i] for i in range(total_chosen)])) these lines formulate the k cheapest items with the highest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
solver.Add(x[i] * cost[i] <= max_cost)
```

This constraint means that we don't want to take expensive items at all. 
That follows that we can exclude the items with `cost[i] > max_cost` before optimization.

```
Sum([profits[i] * x[i])
```

If there is was no other constraints, that objective requests to take the best item `total_chosen` times. But we can not repeat items too often. So, we need 20 best items with a cost less than `max_cost` and repeat them `total_chosen/20` times.

```
import numpy

MAX_ITEMS = 10000

cost = numpy.random.randint(1, 100, MAX_ITEMS)
profits = numpy.random.randint(1, 100, MAX_ITEMS)

total_chosen = 100
repeat = 20 
max_cost = 5.0

cheap = [i for i in range(MAX_ITEMS) if costs[i] <= max_cost]
chosen = sorted(cheap, key=lambda i: profits[i], reverse=True)[:repeat]

for _ in range(total_chosen/repeat):
  for i in chosen:
    print(i, costs[i], profits[i])
```

And with OR tools it will look like

```
import numpy
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

solver = pywraplp.Solver('SolveAssignmentProblemMIP',
                       pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

MAX_ITEMS = 10000

costs = numpy.random.randint(1,100,MAX_ITEMS)
profits = numpy.random.randint(1,100,MAX_ITEMS)

total_chosen = 100
repeat = 20

max_cost = 5.0

x = {}

for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
  x[i] = solver.BoolVar('x[%s]' % (i))

solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i] for i in range(MAX_ITEMS)]) == repeat)

for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
  solver.Add(x[i] * costs[i] <= max_cost)

solver.Maximize(solver.Sum([profits[i] * x[i] for i in range(MAX_ITEMS)]))
sol = solver.Solve()

for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
  if x[i].solution_value() > 0:
    print(i, profits[i], costs[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea, if you create an optimal solution for the first 20 objects, can you repeat the pattern until the end of the sequence?

If yes, sort your items by value, that the 20 best, and repeat that sequence.